# bayes classifier & maximum likelihood classifier

Tags: probability, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

I have got two questions:

Question 1:

Consider a classification task with two classes `t1` and `t2` with prior probabilities `P(t1) = 1/3` and `P(t2) = 2/3`. Show why the Bayes classifier is not equivalent to the maximum likelihood classifier in that case.

My first idea is that the problem is that the prior probability is not i.i.d. (independent identically distributed).

My second idea is that the Bayes classifier considers the prior probability but the maximum likelihood classifier does not.

Question 2:

Suppose both classes can be modeled with a normal distribution with mean values `µ1 = 2` and `µ2 = 7` and standard derivation `σ1 = σ2 = 1`. Use the maximum likelihood classifier to classify the sample `x = 5`. Make sure to explain all steps.

My idea is to do this by derivate the parameters `(µ1, Σ)` and finally set the result to zero. But I am also not sure with this.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you have two questions, you should probably separate them into two questions!

Comment: @HHuang yes, that's right. but the second question is more or less a sub question of the first question. So both belong together.

Comment: You can put a link to the first question in your second question.

Comment: Re: question 2: max likelihood just means this: you try to find the probability (or probability density) of observing $x=5$ given each model, and pick the model with the higher prob (or prob density).  Can you do this?

Comment: @antkam you mean that I have to find the parameters (model) where the likelihood is getting the maximum likelihood? But I think this is what I wrote isn't it? That I have to derivate the parameters and set to zero? Could you please give an example what you mean? That would be great!

Comment: in question 2, the models are already given to you, as $N(2,1)$ and $N(7,1)$.  they're asking, out of these two models, which one has the higher likelihood of generating $x=5$?  (max means highest, and since there are only two models, it just means the higher one.  you are not being asked to generate any new models.  at least that's how i interpret the question.)